# why cannot re-declare same variable name as let and var in js?

Tags: var, let, redeclare

why does
let a= 10;
var a= 10;

throws error that 'a' cannot be re-declared , as much i know , let variable becomes part of script object in js and var becomes part of global object. then why do i get to see this error?

I think it has something to do with block and functional scoping but somehow i'm not able to use that in this context.

Comment: Let's say the compiler accepts your code and the next line of the script is "a = 20;". What happens?

Comment: I suppose JS could bind `20` to `a` in the most-local environment in that case. It would follow the example of other languages that support shadowing. But shadowing isn't a widely venerated feature in languages because it leads to mistakes — and, JS, unless new syntax were added, has even fewer protections against those mistakes than C or Python. Given the pitfalls, I am guessing the JS designers figured not do the work to support it, and just error on it instead.

Comment: I think it has something to with the scope , as both are declared in the same scope, and therefore  being part of different object does not matters in this case.